# Chai Expect a deep array to include not working with Chai-Immutable

Tags: javascript, list, chai, immutable.js, chai-immutable

```
AssertionError: expected 'List [ List [ 0, "a", 0, 0 ], List [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], List [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], List [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]' to include 'a'
```

I use [Chai](http://chaijs.com/) and [`chai-immutable`](https://github.com/astorije/chai-immutable).

I am calling:

```
expect(nextState).to.deep.include("a");
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Hi @Cooper Sinai-Yunker, did my answer resolve your question? :)

Comment: I think so. I figured out a different solution to this a while ago, but it looks like your solution works as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that even though [.include()](https://github.com/astorije/chai-immutable#includevalue) is overridden by `chai-immutable`, it behaves just like Chai does on native arrays:

Consider:

```
expect([
  [0, "a", 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
]).to.deep.include("a");
```

This fails with:

```
 AssertionError: expected [ Array(4) ] to include 'a'
```

To solve this, I see at least 2 ways to do so (as far as I know) using Chai alone. There might also be [Chai plugins](http://chaijs.com/plugins/) to help you with this.

### Using `.flatten`

Immutable.js `List`s come with [`.flatten()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/flatten) which would flatten your matrix of `List`s into a single `List`:

```
expect(new List([
  new List([0, "a", 0, 0]),
  new List([0, 0, 0, 0]),
  new List([0, 0, 0, 0]),
  new List([0, 0, 0, 0]),
]).flatten()).to.deep.include("a");
```

A failure would output like this:

```
AssertionError: expected 'List [ 0, "a", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]' to include 'z'
```

### Using `.satisfy`

Chai has a [`.satisfy()`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_satisfy) assertion that allows for more manual control:

```
expect(new List([
  new List([0, "a", 0, 0]),
  new List([0, 0, 0, 0]),
  new List([0, 0, 0, 0]),
  new List([0, 0, 0, 0]),
])).to.satisfy(matrix => matrix.some(row => row.includes("a")));
```

This avoids flattening the value being tested against, but because `chai-immutable` does not override `.satisfy()`, the output in case of failure is not too pretty:

```
AssertionError: expected { Object (size, _origin, ...) } to satisfy [Function]
```